# what is meaning of ''one'' and ''has got'' in this statement?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Human beings are the only creatures on Earth that claim a God and the only living thing that behaves like it has not got one (from [here](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/576173-human-beings-are-the-only-creatures-on-earth-that-claim))

Does "living thing" mean human?if yes,why is the verb plural but "thing" isn't?

Does "has not got" mean has not understood,and "one" mean singleton?

What is the content of this statement?

Thanks

Comment: That is not good English. Where did you find it?

Comment: @Michael Harvey That is quote by the Rum Diary i see that in picture

Comment: Please copy the text carefully and provide a source every time. It says "Human beings are **the** only creatures on Earth that claim a god and **the** only living thing that behaves like it hasn't got one."

Comment: @Em.Ok i understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a very well constructed sentence.

The first part is fine. The implied clause "(human beings) claim a God" is slightly odd use of claim, but I can understand it.

> Human beings are only creatures on Earth that claim a God

the second part (after and) means

> [human beings are] the only living thing that behaves like it has not got [a God]

Which is uncomfortable as it shifts between the plural and the singular. You can defend it by understanding a "living thing" to refer to a species,  so the plural (human beings) is one species (humanity) but it could probably be rewritten.

The suggestion is that other living things (cats, mosquitos, trees, bacteria) don't say that God exists, but other living things behave as if they are following the will of God.